# Nested classes and business logic in a repository?

Tags: c#, class-design

For my application I need to store some data in an array with the properties (`string main`, `string[] status`, i`nt curParCount`, etc.).

I am currently storing it in this class:

```
class Repository
{
    public static Rep[] rep = new Rep[6];
    public struct Rep
    {
        public string main;
        public string clean;
        public int curParCount;
        public int totalCount;
        public int parStart;
        public int partialStart;
        public double scrollPos;
        public int selectionStart;
        public int selectionEnd;
        public string[] status;
    }    
    public static string repName()
    {
        string name;
        if (MainWindow.repnum == 0)
        { name = "Main Text"; }
        else { name = "Repository " + MainWindow.repnum; }
        return name;
    }
    public static string getStatus(int repNum, int statNum)
    {
        return rep[repNum].status[statNum];
    }                                                                  
 }
```

Is this the right way for me to do this? It sure doesn't feel like it is.

Comment: Why doesn't it feel right? It looks simple and it sounds like it fits your requirements. What's the matter?

Comment: Make it into an entity bean, make all attributes privates and create each getter/setter methods for all your attributes. Your code isn't bad at all, I'm just throwing my 2 cent worth.

Comment: @Elite Gentleman: You're thinking of Java.

Comment: @highone: Are there other members in the Repository class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic idea is fine.  The implementation could be improved.  In particular, I'm concerned that you have a mutable struct; either make it immutable or turn it into a class.  I'd also recommend changing the public fields into public properties with automatic backing fields (and then upper-casing the names).

*edit*

Here's my version:

```
class Repository
{
    public class Rep
    {
        public string Main {get; set;}
        public string Clean {get; set;}
        public int CurParCount {get; set;}
        public int TotalCount {get; set;}
        public int ParStart {get; set;}
        public int PartialStart {get; set;}
        public double ScrollPos {get; set;}
        public int SelectionStart {get; set;}
        public int SelectionEnd {get; set;}
        public string[] Statuses {get; set;}
    }                                       


    public const int StatusCount = 6;
    public static List<Rep> Reps = new List<Rep>();

    public static string Name
    {
        get
        { 
            if (MainWindow.repnum == 0)
              return "Main Text";

            return "Repository " + MainWindow.repnum;
        }
    }

    public static string GetStatus(int repIndex, int statIndex)
    { return Reps[repIndex].Status[statIndex]; }
}
```

Comment: heh, I just assumed he had a reason for using a struct over a class.

Comment: He may well believe that it would be more efficient.  Or, if he has a C++ background, he might not recognize how fundamentally different structs are from classes.

Comment: Can somebody please post a link as to WHY a mutable struct is a bad thing ESPECIALLY in a non-public struct (used internally only)?  Why wrap in properties on implementation details if you're not making "Fancy" code behind the property?  This quirk of C# has never made sense.  Why properties exist is fine, but why you'd do a thin wrapper makes no sense in non-public interfaces.

Comment: @Kevin - The main reason I would suggest class/properties here is that the OP specified WPF, and you need properties for databinding.  But try this: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx

Comment: Using properties gives you the flexibility to change how the property is implemented. If later you decide your property needs to be calculated or retrieved via a web service the client code is insulated from that detail.

Comment: Briefly: These are public fields, so "non-public interface" is not accurate.  Properties let you change the implementation, add logic, set breakpoints.  They're the right way to do this, and within an assembly they are completely free.

Comment: As for struct, it is a value type so it doesn't behave the way you might expect, particularly with regard to boxing.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, that's proof you shouldn't use struct. :-)

Comment: @Kevin: the struct is visible throughout the full scope where Repository is visible, so I would not quite regard it as internal in that sense. Regarding properties, data binding is one argument, future-proofing is another (by wrapping the values in properties you can later add validation or whatever without breaking calling code). I would expose public fields only when there are good reasons to not use a property.

Comment: @Kevin Always wrapping the properties gives you a way to rewire the inner workings of the class in case the need arises in the future, without effecting the interface, public or not, which decreases code impacted by the change.  Yes, I could say to myself "Do I really need a property, or is a field ok?", but doing so is like trying to see in to the future, and spending time thinking about it is a waste of time.  I'd rather just declare them as properties to begin with and not have to deal with it later.  Also, with automatic properties there is no more coding required than declaring a field.

Comment: There are a few rare cases where exposing a public field is necessary.  Barring those, never do it.

Comment: In addition, aaronls is right about the vague abbreviations and Daniel Straight is right about the magic number 6.

Comment: @Steven Sudit: The nested class and the nesting class that has nothing but an array of those instances is a bad thing.  -1 for keeping that.

Comment: Ouch, that stings.  Actually, I'm unwilling to tamper with this aspect without knowing more.  There may well be omitted members of the containing class that explain its existence.  Perhaps highone could clarify.

Comment: I edited my original post so that it now contains everything that is currently in the Repository class.

Comment: One problem with properties they can't be ref'd or out'd as a value type (e.g. int.TryParse() and its ilk).

Comment: I've updated it with the additional members.  Not wild about the design, still.  For example, what's MainWindow and why should Repository know anything about it?

Comment: Oh, and this demonstrates that casperOne was wrong to downvote me.

Comment: @kenny: You're right, but this is not a great tragedy.  All you need is a temp.

Comment: Based on new info from the OP, I changed the array to a list.

Comment: @Steven Sudit- MainWindow is the program's main class. Each Rep basically contains a string of text or rtf as well as information about it such as what the scroll position and selection position were when that string was last displayed in a richtextbox. The repnum is an int in the MainWindow class which represents which Rep's text string is currently on display in the richtextbox.

Comment: @highone: I'd prefer that this class not have any direct knowledge of MainWindow, if possible.  In other words, I'd rather that the name property be a method that gets passed in the MainWindow.repnum.  The reason is that it's not necessary, and therefore interferes with loose coupling.  In general, you may want to brush up on .NET naming conventions, such as capitalization for properties.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the way ***I*** would do it...

```
Public Class Repository: ObservableCollection<RepositoryItem>
{
}


public class RepositoryItem
    {
        public string main {get; set};
        public string clean {get; set};
        public int curParCount {get; set};
        public int totalCount {get; set};
        public int parStart {get; set};
        public int partialStart {get; set};
        public double scrollPos {get; set};
        public int selectionStart {get; set};
        public int selectionEnd {get; set};
        public string[] status {get; };
    }
```

Basically, this is a class of RepositoryItem (which holds your data, and any functions that you may need to utilize to IMPACT that data) and then a class Repository, which inherits the ObservableCollection class, typing it to the RepositoryItem.

Comment: The property should not be an array.

Comment: Actually, as it stands, the status property is permanently null.  That's not good.  (Oh, and properties are uppercase, remember?)

Answer (score 2):

ParStart and PartialStart sound like the same thing.  You should rename one of those fields to make the name more descriptive.  Also, if Par is an abbreviation, then don't abbreviate.  You should generally avoid abbreviations(but acronyms are OK if they are well known).  The same goes for "Rep" if that is an abbreviation.

Additionally I agree with all of Steven's notes.

Answer (score 1):

```
    class RepositoryManager
    {
        private static List<Repository> Repo { get; set; }
        .
        .
        .
    }

    public class Repository          
    {
            public string Main { get; set; }
            public string Clean { get; set; }
            public int CurParCount { get; set; }
            .
            .
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that I would change in order to follow best practices.

First, I would address what the [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) issue you have.  The Rep struct doesn't need to be a nested class, in my opinion, I would remove it, like so (and also call it something else):

```
class Repository 
{ 
    public static Rep[] rep = new Rep[6]; 
}

public struct RepositoryItem
{
    public string main; 
    public string clean; 
    public int curParCount; 
    public int totalCount; 
    public int parStart; 
    public int partialStart; 
    public double scrollPos; 
    public int selectionStart; 
    public int selectionEnd; 
    public string[] status; 
}
```

Now, if you look, you have a Repository class that does nothing but hold the array.  Since that is the case, you can effectively eliminate that and create your array as a variable and store that anywhere you wish.

That leaves the RepositoryItem structure.  I would first address the issues that violate the [design guidelines for class libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czefa0ke(VS.71).aspx).  The biggest offense here is the naming of the fields, they should be [Pascal-cased](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2004/02/03/67024.aspx):

```
public struct RepositoryItem
{
    public string Main; 
    public string Clean; 
    public int CurParCount; 
    public int TotalCount; 
    public int ParStart; 
    public int PartialStart; 
    public double ScrollPos; 
    public int SelectionStart; 
    public int SelectionEnd; 
    public string[] Status; 
}
```

You should also give your field names more *meaningful* names.  While "Pos" might be obvious to you, it might not be obvious to others.  "ScrollPosition" might be a better name than "ScrollPos".

Now, beyond that, it gets a little more subjective.  The questions you have to ask are, should this be a structure (if you want copy-by-value semantics, then great, it should be) or a class?  Also, should the fields be read only (if so, this should be a class and you should have a constructor which takes all the values)?

Also, consider the implications if the properties/fields are read-only.  If the Status field is read only, consider exposing it as an IEnumerable instead of an array, as it will give you much more flexibility in assigning the value as opposed to forcing the contiguous memory that arrays demand (also, you will protect from setting elements in the array, since the reference to the array is read-only, not the elements in the array themselves).

Comment: I might also address the magic number. Why is it exactly 6? Will it ever change?

Comment: @ Daniel Straight- I was originally going to limit the Rep array to a length of 6, but have now decided to change it from an array to a list<string> so that I can change its length. However the Status array will always have a length of 6 as it corresponds with 6 labels.

Comment: @highone -- In my experience, "always" lasts a couple of years at best. ;)

Comment: "Always" lasts about as long as "never". :-)